# Styling of "submit" buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I am wondering if anyone knows why the "default" style of a "submit" button looks pretty good (corners slightly rounded, some gradient from top to bottom, etc.) but the moment I add a background color it changes to a 1990's era square button with 2px border...just looks awful.

Can I somehow keep most of the default styling but change the background color?

Comment: All buttons are like that. Form controls in HTML are fugly.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781693/changing-backgroundcolor-changes-border

Comment: In case you're [interested in seeing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12454721/451969) the browser chrome's stylesheets and whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (modern) browser (or [css framework like bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)) contains default styling for submit buttons (so it will look `"pretty good (corners slightly rounded, some gradient from top to bottom, etc.)"` and not like the 1990's buttons).

When you override those gradients in your css (by changing `background-color`), you are overriding those programmed defaults your browser was using. Instead of only changing the  background color, you can make your own nice gradient. **And**, as @ŠimeVidas pointed out in the comments, changing background color will also remove the default `border-style` too.

I'd recommend [using a gradient generator](http://www.cssdrive.com/css3button/) instead of simply changing `background-color`.

Comment: But setting a `background-color` will also disable the border styles. That was OP's question. Can you explain that?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas is that so? either way, a button gradient generator will allow you to change that too. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Browsers come with a big set of default styles to make things look pretty if the styles are not set by the website. For example Firefox has the following styles defined for the default submit button:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -moz-binding: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-color: buttonface;
    border: 2px outset buttonface;
    color: buttontext;
    cursor: default;
    font: -moz-button;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[`-moz-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance) is a non-standard property, that defines the style to be consistent with the operating system’s default button style. That’s why it will look different on different operating systems too.

Comment: I'm confused; `buttonface`, although cute, is the cause of the problem along with `border-image` and `color`. `-moz-appearance` is `button`, never changes. http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9eDXt/

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is that the default background is a quite complex gradient.

I advise you to take a framework like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) or [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) to design your buttons. This is much easier and you will achieve probabily better results than searching your own background-gradient for your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can make beautiful buttons with just a little CSS. Check out these references:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons

http://css3button.net/

Comment: I love what they did when you open css3button.net via IE8 ! :D