# Input box getting thicker after a CSS background-color modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form which is validated through a Javascript script.
One of the function of that script is to highlight input fields that have been modified from the original values they contained.

It works, but when one of the input field is highlighted, it become thicker than when it is normally.

The JS script just add a class to the input box:

```
function evidenzia_cambiamenti(id,testo) {
    if (typeof(testo) === 'undefined') testo = '';
    if ((document.getElementById(id).value != testo)) {
        $('#'+id).addClass('campo_modificato');
        $('#'+id).removeClass("errore_campo");
        $('#'+id).removeClass("campo_obbligatorio");
    } else if (document.getElementById(id).value == testo) {
        $('#'+id).removeClass('campo_modificato');
    }
}
```

while the CSS class just modifies the background color:

```
.campo_modificato {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

Though none of the actions remove the default property of input box, I can't understand the difference between the two views:

- [image]
   -> not-highlighted field
- [image]
   -> highlighted field

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781693/changing-backgroundcolor-changes-border

Comment: In what way does the duplicate question not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css: given this class is applied to input

```
input.campo_modificato:focus {
    border-style: solid;
}
```